# How can I change the date component of an Oracle timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g, timestamp

I have an Oracle `TIMESTAMP` column, which contains values such as:

```
2019-11-05 15:16:31
```

I would like to update these rows to change the date component from 5th November 2019 to 8th June 2020, without changing the time component. I understand that underneath this is just a numeric value, with no separation of year/month/day/hour/minute/second/etc. The aim is that the above value becomes:

```
2020-06-08 15:16:31
```

The best I can come up with is:

```
update mytable set tscolumn = tscolumn + 216
```

(with appropriate where clause of course)

which works but isn't particularly pretty and relies on [TimeAndDate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=05&m1=11&y1=2019&d2=08&m2=6&y2=2020)

Comment: What don't you like about your solution?

Comment: I don't like the fact that I have to rely on going to timeAndDate first to find out the number of days. I'd rather a more explicit solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `TIMESTAMP` literal where the time is set to midnight and then add the time component from your row, which you can work out by subtracting the `TRUNC`ated column value from the non-truncated column value:

```sql
UPDATE mytable
SET tscolumn = TIMESTAMP '2020-06-08 00:00:00'
               + ( tscolumn - TRUNC( tscolumn ) ) DAY TO SECOND;
```

*(`DAY TO SECOND` is included so that the subtraction is done as an `INTERVAL` data type rather than Oracle's default of a numeric difference.)*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable ( tscolumn ) AS
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-11-05 15:16:31' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | TSCOLUMN                      |
> | :---------------------------- |
> | 2020-06-08 15:16:31.000000000 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ba1a85a9df59e8d23d3f8a15aec8a952)*

Answer (score 0):

One option uses date artithmetics:

```
update mytable 
set tscolumn = tscolumn + (date '2020-06-08' - date '2019-11-05')
where tscolumn >= date '2019-11-05' and tscolumn < date '2019-11-06'
```

The substraction between the literal dates gives you the number of days in between.

Note that I added a `where` clause to the query so it only applies on columns whose date part is `'2019-11-05'` - it is unclear what you want to do with other dates.

If you really have a `timestamp` column and you want to preserve the fractional seconds, then you want to use intervals:

```
update mytable 
set tscolumn = tscolumn + (date '2020-06-08' - date '2019-11-05') * interval '1' day
where tscolumn >= date '2019-11-05' and tscolumn < date '2019-11-06'
```

Comment: `TIMESTAMP + NUMBER` is not a supported operation so Oracle will implicitly convert this to `CAST( tscolumn AS DATE ) + (date '2020-06-08' - date '2019-11-05')` and you will lose the fractional seconds from the time component. Given that the OP is using a `TIMESTAMP` data type rather than a `DATE` (which also has a time component, just without fractional seconds) then this is probably important data that is being lost. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=309b560280bb41799ef39818ca60860e)

Comment: @MT0: yes that's a good point. I did not pay attention to that, since OP was doing the `+ number` operation in the first place... But indeed they stated that they have a `timestamp` column. I edited my answer;